# How to split 3rd order multidimensional array into different arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, trading, algorithmic-trading

I'm making a crypto currency analysis script, the exchange api bundles the market spread in one JSON object, which prints this-

```
{'error': [], 'result': {'XXBTZEUR': {'asks': [['892.00000', '0.067', 
1489866640]], 'bids': [['891.86000', '0.032', 1489866639]]}}}
```

As you can see, this is a multidimensional array. Let me simplify it's structure for you.

```
c = {'a':[],'b':{'bsubarray':{'asks':[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...]
                             {'bids':[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...]}
```

I'm trying to get 4 arrays out of this- `ask_x` and `ask_y` and `bid_x` and `bid_y`

This is literally my third program in python, so any detailed explanation would really help me learn.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract `ask_x`, `ask_y`, etc. then you just need to `zip` up the relevant `asks`, etc, e.g.:

```
>>> c = {'a':[],'b':{'bsubarray':{'asks':[['x1','y1','z1'],['x2','y2','z2'],['x3','y3','z3']],
...                               'bids':[['x1','y1','z1'],['x2','y2','z2'],['x3','y3','z3']]}}}
>>> ask_x, ask_y, ask_z = zip(*c['b']['bsubarray']['asks'])
>>> bid_x, bid_y, bid_z = zip(*c['b']['bsubarray']['bids'])
>>> ask_x
('x1', 'x2', 'x3')
>>> ask_y
('y1', 'y2', 'y3')
```

Using your actual data:

```
>>> c = {'error': [], 'result': {'XXBTZEUR': {'asks': [['892.00000', '0.067', 1489866640]], 
...                                           'bids': [['891.86000', '0.032', 1489866639]]}}}
>>> ask_x, ask_y, ask_z = zip(*c['result']['XXBTZEUR']['asks'])
>>> bid_x, bid_y, bid_z = zip(*c['result']['XXBTZEUR']['bids'])
>>> ask_x
('892.00000',)
>>> ask_y
('0.067',)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, solved!!
~Thank you for the answer, super helpful. Is there a way for ask_x to contain all the x (x1, x2, x3...) entries of the ask array?~

Comment: It does contain all `(x1, x2, x3)` - `('x1', 'x2', 'x3')` your example only has one item in it.